# Ito integral related proofs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W = (Wt)_{t\geq0}$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion. Prove that
$$\int_{0}^{t} W_s^2 dW_s= \frac{1} {3} W_t^3-\int_{0}^{t}W_sds$$
$$\int_{0}^{t} sdW_s=tW_t-\int_{0}^{t}W_sds$$
I found this exercise online while preparing for exam and I am clueless.The only thing I have noticed is that the term $ \int_{0}^{t}W_sds$ looks like $\int_{0}^{t}F'(X_s)dX_s$ from Ito theorem.

Could you help me with solution?

Comment: Recall Ito's formula - if $f$ is $C^2$ then $$f(W_t) = f(W_0) + \int_0^t f'(W_s)\ \mathsf dW_s + \frac12 \int_0^tf''(W_s)\ \mathsf ds.$$ Apply this to $f(x)=x^3$ for the first identity.

Comment: Thanks, and what is f(x) equal to in the second case?

Comment: The second identity follows from integration by parts.

Comment: Could you please write it down? I am not entirely familiar with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second one use integration by parts formula. The integration by parts formula states that if $X$ and $Y$ are two processes then

$$ d(X_t Y_t) = X_t dY_t+ Y_t dX_t + dX_t\cdot dY_t$$

In your case, we set $X=W_t$ and $Y_t=t$. Then

$$ d(W_t t) = W_t dt + t dW_t + dt\cdot dW_t$$

From "multiplication table," we know that $dt\cdot dW_t=0$. So that

$$ d(W_t t) = W_t dt + t dW_t$$

or, in the integral form,
$$ t W_t = \int_0^tW_s ds+\int_0^t s dW_s $$